# How to extract nested password protected zip folders using PowerShell a specified number of times?

Tags: bash, powershell, zip

I have a zip folder that contains a `password{i}.txt` file and a `zip{i}.zip` folder. I have to extract the password-protected zip using the password from `password{i}.txt`. Then, `zip{i+1}.zip` is also password protected (inside of `zip{i}`) and I have to do the same thing. Given 999 nested directories, I have to keep extracting until I reach a final `answer`that is in a file.

The source code for doing this in bash is quite simple and easy to follow.

```
for ((i = 999 ; i >= 0 ; i--))
do
  pass=`cat password${i}.txt`
  rm password${i}.txt
  unzip -P $pass zip${i}.zip
  rm zip${i}.zip
done
```

I am learning PowerShell, but I am having trouble creating the code for it. How would I implement something similar using PowerShell? I am assuming the source is also quite short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using multiple ways, but I had to download a dependency of some sort for the file extraction (with a password). I used `7Zip4Powershell` and the code functions identical to the bash version.

```
$curr = Get-Location 
for ($i=999; $i-ge 0; $i--) {
    $pwd = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("password$i.txt"); 
    Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName "zip$i.zip" -TargetPath $curr -Password $pwd
    rm "password$i.txt"
    rm "zip$i.zip"
}
```